# Prevent site data from being crawled and ripped

Tags: web-crawler, spam-prevention

I'm looking into building a content site with possibly thousands of different entries, accessible by index and by search.

What are the measures I can take to prevent **malicious crawlers** from ripping off all the data from my site? I'm less worried about SEO, although I wouldn't want to block legitimate crawlers all together.

For example, I thought about randomly changing small bits of the HTML structure used to display my data, but I guess it wouldn't really be effective.

Comment: I found this thread because I have experienced this problem first hand. I find it hard to believe that nobody mentioned .htaccess in the directory of protected files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any site that it visible by human eyes is, in theory, potentially rippable. If you're going to even try to be accessible then this, by definition, **must** be the case (how else will speaking browsers be able to deliver your content if it isn't machine readable).

Your best bet is to look into watermarking your content, so that at least if it does get ripped you can point to the watermarks and claim ownership.

Answer (score 14):

Between this:

> What are the measures I can take to prevent malicious crawlers from ripping

and this:

> I wouldn't want to block legitimate crawlers all together.

you're asking for a lot. Fact is, if you're going to try and block malicious scrapers, you're going to end up blocking all the "good" crawlers too.

You have to remember that if people want to scrape your content, they're going to put in a lot more manual effort than a search engine bot will... So get your priorities right. You've two choices:

1. Let the peasants of the internet steal your content. Keep an eye out for it (searching Google for some of your more unique phrases) and sending take-down requests to ISPs. This choice has barely any impact on your apart from the time.
2. Use AJAX and rolling encryption to request all your content from the server. You'll need to keep the method changing, or even random so each pageload carries a different encryption scheme. But even this ***will*** be cracked if somebody wants to crack it. You'll also drop off the face of the search engines and therefore take a hit in traffic of real users.

Answer (score 6):

Good crawlers will follow the rules you specify in your robots.txt, malicious ones will not. 
You can set up a "trap" for bad robots, like it is explained here:
http://www.fleiner.com/bots/.
But then again, if you put your content on the internet, I think it's better for everyone if it's as painless as possible to find (in fact, you're posting here and not at some lame forum where *experts exchange* their opinions)

Comment: That link for "Bad" Robots looks very promising. Thanks.

Comment: You mean... where expert sex change their opinions?

Answer (score 6):

Realistically you can't stop malicious crawlers - and any measures that you put in place to prevent them are likely to harm your legitimate users (aside from perhaps adding entries to robots.txt to allow detection)

So what you have to do is to plan on the content being stolen - it's more than likely to happen in one form or another - and understand how you will deal with unauthorized copying.

Prevention isn't possible - and will be a waste of your time trying to make it so.

The only sure way of making sure that the content on a website isn't vulnerable to copying is to unplug the network cable...

To detect it use something like http://www.copyscape.com/ may help.

Answer (score 5):

Don't even try to erect limits on the web!

It really is as simple as this.

Every potential measure to discourage ripping (aside from a very strict robots.txt) will harm your users. Captchas are more pain than gain. Checking the user agent shuts out unexpected browsers. The same is true for "clever" tricks with javascript.

Please keep the web open. If you don't want anything to be taken from your website, then do not publish it there. Watermarks can help you claim ownership, but that only helps when you want to sue after the harm is done.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to stop a site being machine ripped is to make the user prove that they are human.

You could make users perform a task that is easy for humans and hard for machines, eg: CAPTCHA. When a user first gets to your site present a CAPTCHA and only allow them to proceed once it has completed. If the user starts moving from page to page too quickly re-verify.

This is not 100% effective and hackers are always trying to break them.

Alternatively you could make slow responses. You don't need to make them crawl, but pick a speed that is reasonable for humans (this would be very slow for a machine). This just makes them take longer to scrape your site, but not impossible.

OK. Out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

In short: you cannot prevent ripping. Malicious bots commonly use IE user agents and are fairly intelligent nowadays. If you want to have your site accessible to the maximum number (ie screenreaders, etc) you cannot use javascript or one of the popular plugins (flash) simply because they can inhibit a legitimate user's access.

Perhaps you could have a cron job that picks a random snippet out of your database and googles it to check for matches. You could then try and get hold of the offending site and demand they take the content down.

You could also monitor the number of requests from a given IP and block it if it passes a threshold, although you may have to whitelist legitimate bots and would be no use against a botnet (but if you are up against a botnet, perhaps ripping is not your biggest problem).

Answer (score 2):

If you're making a public site, then it's very difficult.  There are methods that involve server-side scripting to generate content or the use of non-text (Flash, etc) to minimize the likelihood of ripping.

But to be honest, if you consider your content to be so good, just password-protect it and remove it from the public arena.

My opinion is that the whole point of the web is to propagate useful content to as many people as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the content is public and freely available, even with page view throttling or whatever, there is nothing you can do. If you require registration and/or payment to access the data, you might restrict it a bit, and at least you can see who reads what and identify the users that seem to be scraping your entire database.

However I think you should rather face the fact that this is how the net works, there are not many ways to prevent a machine to read what a human can. Outputting all your content as images would of course discourage most, but then the site is not accessible anymore, let alone the fact that even the non-disabled users will not be able to copy-paste anything - which can be really annoying.

All in all this sounds like DRM/game protection systems - pissing the hell out of your legit users only to prevent some bad behavior that you can't really prevent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Flash / Silverlight / Java to display all your page contents. That would probably stop most crawlers in their tracks.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a system that would block or allow based on the User-Agent header.
It relies on the crawler setting their User-Agent but it seems most of them do.

It won't work if they use a fake header to emulate a popular browser of course.

Answer (score -1):

Use where ever is possible human validators and try using some framework (MVC). The site ripping software is sometimes unable to rip this kind of page. Also detect the user agent, at least it will reduce the number of possible rippers