# What you do to prevent spambots?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, web-crawler, spam-prevention

we have a website that sometimes gets stuck because of spambots, we tried to block the ips of them but it's not a good idea because they could have a dynamic ip, do someone have a good way to stop them, we tried to use Dynamic IP Restricion that found in IIS but did not help too much.

What you do to prevent spambots?!

Comment: Might I suggest that you accept answers to some of your previous questions. People may be more inclined to help you if you do.

Comment: How can I select answer? I cannot find anything to do that!

Comment: Click the little check mark on the correct answer, under the voting arrows.

Comment: Good luck stopping them :)  If you find a way please post it as I think most people would like to do this it's just not possible to stop them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two common solutions is to use Honeypot detection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29

and Captcha: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha

Comment: Both are not valid for our case since we are looking to block bad crawler to crawl our website and and steal our contents.

Comment: If you don't want people taking your content then don't put it on the net, I don't mean to sound crass by saying so, that's just the fact of web development.  If you're still interested in protecting your content, check this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177479/prevent-site-data-from-being-crawled-and-ripped

Comment: My object is to prevent bad robots to enter our site and put load traffi con it.

Comment: My solution to that is don't waste your time trying.  Otherwise view the link I posted in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a common white-label forum like PhpBB or Invision? If so, I suggest renaming the common pages as most bots just check to see if you have a page like "createThread.php" or "respond.php". Most aren't smart, and most won't bother to write a specific spam script for your site - they just spray and pray.