# Can dynamically generated web paged be crawled and scraped by bots?

Tags: php, security, ssl, bots

I have a web site that organizations use to maintain membership information. The data is stored in a MySQL database on a GoDaddy server. The site includes SSL so it is a https web address. Users must authenticate to get onto the site.

Once logged in, a user can access a page that generates a team roster. The page is created server side using PHP which fetches data from the MySQL database, then creates the page. The team roster includes member's email address.

Is it possible for a web bot to scrape email address information from the team roster web page?

Comment: There are in memory web browsers can use that will allow a bot to completely recreate a web page in the same way if a person loaded it in a web browser. It's slower so don't know how many bots do this, but as someone who has written something to do that for UI testing I can say it definitely can be done.

Comment: bot's (usually)dont log in, so if you have the usual password-user name login, then your safe.

Comment: So if one of my users has authenticated in, then accessed the team roster page, is the page content safe from a bot while the user is viewing the page?

Comment: totally safe assuming you haven't done anything crazy with the authentication system.

Comment: Great! Good to hear. Thanks. I assumed I had done everything right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent site data from being crawled and ripped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177479/prevent-site-data-from-being-crawled-and-ripped)