# Google enters my git repo into the search engine

Tags: gitlab, repository, seo

I googled my domain name by accident and I get that google its spyder crawled my repo link for no reason, how can I avoid this and things do I signal google to take down the visible site?

Comment: Maybe this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177479/prevent-site-data-from-being-crawled-and-ripped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent site data from being crawled and ripped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177479/prevent-site-data-from-being-crawled-and-ripped)

Comment: What does this have to do with GitLab?

Comment: What do you mean by "repo link"?  Did you publish the source code somewhere (like GitHub?)